# How to fix recent "Clock skew detected" warning after updating msys2?

Tags: mingw, gnu-make, updates, msys2, mingw32

After updating msys2 with "pacman -Syu".

the 32bit version of MinGW doesn't work normally by spamming a lot of weird "Clock skew detected" warnings.

```
mingw32-make[4]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles\Makefile2' has modification time 4.3e+09 s in the future
mingw32-make[5]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles\common.dir\build.make' has modification time 2.8e+16 s in the future
mingw32-make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
mingw32-make[5]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles\common.dir\build.make' has modification time 2.8e+16 s in the future
```

and many more ...

This happen with my home installation and fresh installation from runner like Github actions.

Am I the only one with this problem and how can I fix it ?

Maybe related to mingw32-make ? :

- version where it work : GNU Make 4.3
- version where it doesn't : GNU Make 4.4

For now I use a bit older msys2 packages on another computer and it work fine, one of the package is causing this trouble on a recent update.

Comment: If you didn't do anything with the clock, you should report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed in : https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/13834

version "mingw-w64-i686-make-4.4-2"